# C++ compiler not letting me use an array as parameter to function call in a userdefined function

Tags: c++, arrays, user-defined-functions

C++ compiler not letting me use an array as parameter to function call in a userdefined function. Can some one explain this to me and help me with a solution?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double GetAverage(int[], int = 10);
int GetAboveAverage(int[], int = 10);
const int ARRAYSIZE = 10;

void main()
{

    int mArray[ARRAYSIZE];

    cout << "Input the first number" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i <= ARRAYSIZE - 1; i++)
    {
        cin >> mArray[i];
        cout << "Input the next number" << endl;
    }

    cout << "The average of the nummbers is " << GetAverage(mArray, ARRAYSIZE) << endl;
    cout <<"The the amount above average is " << GetAboveAverage(mArray, ARRAYSIZE) <<endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

The function whit the problem calls this function.

```
double GetAverage(int fArray[], int arrSize)
{

    int sum = 0;
    int average;

    for (int i = 0; i <= arrSize- 1; i++)
    sum += fArray[i];
    average = sum / arrSize;

    return average;
}
```

Hear is where the problem is.

```
int GetAboveAverage(int gArray[], int arrSize)
{
    int amtAboveAve;
    int average = GetAverage( gArray[], arrSize); //where i get the error its on the bracket and it says "error: expected and expression"
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        if (gArray[i] > average)
            amtAboveAve++;
    return amtAboveAve;

}
```

Comment: You need to pass `gArray`, not `gArray[]`. `gArray[]` is meaningless in this context.

Comment: O thank you, just wondering why?

Comment: You only use empty square brackets in a declaration - for example, in the argument list, `int gArray[]` is a declaration. Parameters passed to functions are expressions, not declarations. Hence the error "expected an expression".

Comment: O, now it makes sense, my programming teacher decided to rush this unit. Ether way, thank you very much.

Comment: @RosarioPulella I provided an answer. I just realised that it is more or less the same thing what the commenters have said here, so please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the green tick below the voting buttons.

Comment: sorry i don't relay use this website did not know how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass `gArray[]` as-is as it's meaningless in the context you're trying to use it. This is because `gArray[]` attempts to declare an *argument list* as it is a ***declaration***, of which cannot be passed as a *parameter* in a function.

The exact error you're probably getting for this is:

> Error #[error number here]: expected an expression

Your function declaration wants an *expression*, not a *declaration*.

Instead, simply use `gArray` without the brackets in the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the brackets when passing an array to a function.

Replace this:

```
    int average = GetAverage( gArray[], arrSize);
```

With this:

```
    int average = GetAverage( gArray, arrSize);
```